# IIS reverse proxy to Apache

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I'm having a heckuva time getting this working. I've followed the instructions found at:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/

As a simple test, I'm trying to proxy requests for anything in my media directory (CSS, images, etc) to the same directory on a separate host.  Here's the configuration:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(media/.*)" />
            <conditions>
                 <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://mystatichost/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

And in my `Default.master` I've got an image tag like so:

```
<img src="/media/img/homepage.jpg" />
```

But I keep getting a 404 error for that image request. The file `/media/img/homepage.jpg` definitely exists on `mystatichost`. What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: I've not been able to get Reverse Proxy working with this technique.  Did you ever manage it?  URL re-direction works, but not re-writing / reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there is something a bit odd with your Regular Expression there.

Instead of `<match url="^(media/.*)" />`, you should be using `<match url="(media/.*)" />`. Otherwise your matches only commence from the beginning of the URL string, which is never going to work because it will always start with `http`.

So, to cut it short, try this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(media/.*)" />
        <conditions>
             <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://mystatichost/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If that doesnt work, do you need HTTPS for all your requests to mystatichost?

Perhaps you can remove the `<conditions>` section and then set `<action type="Rewrite" url="http://mystatichost/{R:1}" />`.

Good luck!